# Multiply each slice of image by weights

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training a network such that one of tensor `t1` has following shape:

`shape(t1) = [?, 300, 300, 10]`

and another tensor `t2` has shape:

`shape(t2) = [?, 10]`

I would like to multiple each element of `t2` tensor by each slice `[300, 300]` of tensor `t1`. Any body know how to do that? So far I've written following:

```
def mul_concat(I):
    A = []
    for i in range(d1.shape[1].value):
        A.append(d1[:, i]*I[:, :, :, i]))
return reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, A)
```

However, I get error because of the `batch size` dimension. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: The slices of tensor `t1` are of the dimension `[300, 300, 10]`. Could you give a concrete example of the multiplication by fixing the shape of the tensors to, say, 1?

Comment: I meant to say slices of each element of batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reshape `t2` to shape `[?, 1, 1, 10]`, then Tensorflow's broadcasting rules will do the rest:

```
t2_reshaped = tf.reshape(t2, [-1, 1, 1, 10])
output = t1 * t2_reshaped
```

Many Tensorflow operators allow broadcasting; the rules for broadcasting are the same as `numpy`'s rules for broadcasting. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: It works but the results and multiplication were not how I wanted. However, that did put me in right direction.